# Twilio Notification not received when apn payload is overridden

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, twilio

I'm using the Twilio Java SDK to send push notifications to my mobile app. I'm trying to override the APN payload in order to set the "badge" property, so that a badge will appear on the iOS app's icon. With the code below, I successfully receive a notification when I comment out the call to notificationCreator.setApn, but I don't receive a notification if I do call setApn. I imagine that there's a problem with the APN payload that I'm creating. 
This is the code:

```
NotificationCreator notificationCreator =
    Notification.creator(BuildConfig.TWILIO_NOTIFY_SID)
        .setIdentity(notifyeeId)
        .setBody(body);

// Aps is a POJO class that mirrors the format of a
// notification's APS dictionary.
Aps aps = ApsBuilder.simpleAlertBuilder(body)
              .setBadge(getBadgeCount(notifyeeId))
              .setMutableContent(mutable)
              .build();

// buildApnOverride converts Aps to JSON and returns
// a map mapping "aps" to that JSON.
Map<String, Object> apnOverride = buildApnOverride(aps);
logger.debug(String.format("apnOverride=%s", SharedObjects.getGson().toJson(apnOverride).toString()));
notificationCreator.setApn(apnOverride);

// Some code that I've omitted calls notificationCreator.setData
// to add some custom data.  

Notification notification = notificationCreator.create();
logger.debug(String.format("notification=%s", SharedObjects.getGson().toJson(notification).toString()));
```

This is the output of the log:

> ```
> apnOverride=
> {
>     "aps": "{\"alert\":{\"body\":\"A patient booked a visit with you\"},\"badge\":3,\"sound\":\"default\",\"mutable-content\":1}"
> }
> notification=
> {
>     "sid": "XXX",
>     "accountSid": "XXX",
>     "serviceSid": "XXX",
>     "dateCreated": {
>         "iMillis": 1517854346000,
>         "iChronology": {
>             "iBase": {
>                 "iMinDaysInFirstWeek": 4
>             }
>         }
>     },
>     "identities": [
>         "XXX"
>     ],
>     "tags": [],
>     "segments": [],
>     "priority": "HIGH",
>     "ttl": 2419200,
>     "body": "A patient booked a visit with you",
>     "data": {
>         "com.doctheapp.notificationData": "{\"type\":\"APPOINTMENT_BOOKED\",\"attributes\":[\"REFRESH_ACTIVITY_FEED\",\"REFRESH_DOCTOR_SCHEDULE\"],\"additionalData\":\"{\\\"appointmentStartTime\\\":\\\"2018-02-05T19:45Z\\\",\\\"serviceName\\\":\\\"New Patient Visit\\\"}\"}"
>     },
>     "apn": {
>         "aps": "{\"alert\":{\"body\":\"A patient booked a visit with you\"},\"badge\":3,\"sound\":\"default\",\"mutable-content\":1}"
>     }
> }
> ```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: I tried copy-pasting Twilio's example code here (https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/notify/rest/notifications?code-sample=code-send-a-detailed-notification&code-language=java&code-sdk-version=7.x), and I had the same problem. I receive a notification only if I comment out the call to setApn.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I see you're trying to override the APNs notification with this (broken out for easier readability):

```
{
  "aps": "{
    \"alert\":{
      \"body\":\"A patient booked a visit with you\"
    },
    \"badge\":3,
    \"sound\":\"default\",
    \"mutable-content\":1
  }"
}
```

As you are using `mutable-content` I looked through the documentation and found this page on [modifying and presenting notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ModifyingNotifications.html). It says:

> When creating the payload for the remote notification, your server should do the following:
>
> - Include the mutable-content key with a value of 1.
> - Include an alert dictionary with subkeys for the title and body of the alert.

I notice your notification only included a body. Can you try setting a title too?

Let me know if this helps at all